# Getting Values from DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: android

I have 2 datepickers and 2 timepickers on a screen and also a submit button. The user selects the start date, start time, end date, and end time. The program then takes these values and stores them into variables, however the variables only return the default values for these controls. Is there anyway to get the updated value from each of these controls?

My code looks like this for the edit screen:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.editscreen);

    timepickerStart = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    timepickerEnd = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker2);
    datepickerStart = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    datepickerEnd = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker2);

    submitbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

    locationText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.locationText);
    eventText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eventText);

}

public void DateStart(View v)
{
    GlobalVariables.datepickerYearStart = datepickerStart.getYear();
    GlobalVariables.datepickerMonthStart = datepickerStart.getMonth();
    GlobalVariables.datepickerDayStart = datepickerStart.getDayOfMonth();
}

public void DateEnd(View v)
{
    GlobalVariables.datepickerYearEnd = datepickerEnd.getYear();
    GlobalVariables.datepickerMonthEnd = datepickerEnd.getMonth();
    GlobalVariables.datepickerDayEnd = datepickerEnd.getDayOfMonth();
}

public void TimeStart(View v)
{
    GlobalVariables.timepickerHourStart = timepickerStart.getCurrentHour();
    GlobalVariables.timepickerMinuteStart = timepickerStart.getCurrentMinute();
}

public void TimeEnd(View v)
{
    GlobalVariables.timepickerHourEnd = timepickerEnd.getCurrentHour();
    GlobalVariables.timepickerMinuteEnd = timepickerEnd.getCurrentMinute();
}

public void submitClicked(View v)
{

    startActivity(new Intent(this, AddToCalendar.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewrite**

Looking at your current code, let's stick with the various `get` methods from DatePicker and TimePicker. However you never call `DateStart()` or any of the others, they look like you have them set up for an OnClickListener... Regardless, try this:

```
public void submitClick(View v) {
    DateStart(null);
    TimeStart(null);
    DateEnd(null);
    TimeEnd(null);

    // Do what you please your GlobalVariables
}
```

---

Though I might leave out the multiple `GlobalVariables` and store one `long` value for each date/time:

```
public void submitClick(View v) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(datepickerStart.getYear(), datepickerStart.getMonth(),
                 datepickerStart.getDayOfMonth(), timepickerStart.getCurrentHour(), 
                 timepickerStart.getCurrentMinute(), 0);
    long startTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    // And similar approach for the end time, then use them however you please
}
```

Comment: How would I use the OnDateChanged and OnTimeChanged in this situation. The only examples I can find involve using a DialogBoxPopup, which is something I don't want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a listener to your DatePicker:

```
    DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(this);
    picker.init(<year>, <monthOfYear>, <dayOfMonth>, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            //set the value of the variable here 
        }
    });
```